# How to apply operation on each column in datafarme and assign it inbetween the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply operations on every column in a dataframe.

original data frame

| c0 | c1. | c2. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

Operation

```
v1=[0,1,1,2,3,4,5]

opp=(previous_column-v1)
```

example for creating new column next to 1st column

```
opp=(previous_column-v1)
opp=(1-0)
opp=1
```

1st value in v1 is applicable to column 1, 2nd value for 2nd column and so on.

I tried the following code for last column

```
df[7]=(df[6]-5)
```

This creates column 7 and applies the operation. What I want is to create a new columns next to existing columns and apply operation on previous column

Expected output:

| c0 | c1 | c2. | c3. | c4. | c5. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | (1-0)=1 | 2 | (2-1)=1 | 3. | (3-1)=2 |
| 2 | (2-0)=1. | 3. | (3-1)=1. | 4. | (4-1)=3. |

Comment: Please provide the explicit expected output, not "*apply opp*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
v1=[0,1,1,2,3,4,5]

# define final order of columns
order = (np.tile([0,df.shape[1]], df.shape[1])
        +np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1]), 2)
        )

# subtract, concat, reorder
out = (pd.concat([df, df.sub(v1[:df.shape[1]]).add_suffix('_op')],
                 axis=1)
         .iloc[:, order]
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   c0  c0_op  c1  c1_op  c2  c2_op
0   1      1   2      1   3      2
1   2      2   3      2   4      3
```

If you rather want a new column index:

```
v1=[0,1,1,2,3,4,5]

# define final order of columns
order = (np.tile([0,df.shape[1]], df.shape[1])
        +np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1]), 2)
        )

# subtract, concat, reorder
out = (pd.concat([df, df.sub(v1[:df.shape[1]])],
                 axis=1, ignore_index=True)
         .iloc[:, order].set_axis(range(df.shape[1]*2), axis=1)
       )
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  2  1  3  2
1  2  2  3  2  4  3
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to programming. If I want to apply further operations like  opp=(previous_column-v1) * v1. How can I do that.

Comment: `df.sub(v1[:df.shape[1]]).mul(v1[:df.shape[1]])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df1.to_numpy()),pd.DataFrame(df1.to_numpy()-v1[:len(df1.columns)])],axis=1)\
    .sort_index(axis=1).set_axis("c0    c1  c2. c3. c4. c5.".split("\t"),axis=1)
```

out：

```
   c0  c1  c2.  c3.  c4.  c5.
0   1   1    2    1    3    2
1   2   2    3    2    4    3
```